# Python ¿Como se suman valores de listas en diccionarios?

Tags: python, diccionarios

estoy bastante perdido y no se como hacer lo siguiente:

Necesito obtener la suma de cada venta por año del siguiente diccionario:

*[venta, año, cantidad, cantidad]*

```
diccionario = {

["venta1","2008","4","3"],

["venta4","2015","2","8"],

["venta1","2012","6","4"],

["venta3","2003","4","3"],

]"venta2","2020","8","13"],

["venta1","2008","6","2"]

}
```

La idea principal es que en el diccionario hay tres venta1, pero dos venta1 2008 y se deben sumar la posición dos de cada lista y la posición tres de cada lista repetida en nombre y fecha, la salida debe ser algo como:

venta1 en el 2008 = 10 y 5 (es la suma en venta1 del 2008)

venta1 en el 2012 = 6 y 4 (es la suma en venta1 del 2012, solo hay un venta1 2012)

venta4 en el 2015 = 2 y 8

venta3 en el 2003 = 4 y 3

La verdad llevo un par de días y no se como hacerlo

Gracias

**archivo.txt** :

```
venta1,2008,4,3
venta4,2015,2,8
venta1,2012,6,4
venta3,2003,4,3
venta2,2020,8,13
venta1,2008,6,7
```

Pasar esas lineas a Diccionario separado en listas:

```
with open("archivo.txt", "r") as listas:
    for linea in listas:
        linea = linea.replace("\n","")
        datos = linea.split(",")
```

Comment: Adjunta lo que has intentado (**código**).

Comment: Hola, debo tomar los datos de un archivo.txt, logre pasar las lineas del archivo a lista dentro de un diccionario, pero me pierdo al intentar tomar el valor 0 de todas las listas que tienen venta1 en la posición 0 decir algo como "Si venta1 es igual a venta1 entonces tomar las listas que tienen ventas1 (que son tres) y ahora comparar la posición 1 que es el año, si son iguales sumar las posiciones 2 y las 3 de esas listas (que son 2 ventas1 2008).        with open("archivo.txt", "r") as listas:
    for linea in listas:
        linea = linea.replace("\n","")
        datos = linea.split(",")

Answer (score 2):

La variable que pones al principio llamada `diccionario`, no es un diccionario, es otra estructura de datos llamada [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), la cual es muy parecida a una lista, pero no permite valores repetidos, además de ciertas otras limitaciones.

```
var1 = {key1:value1, key2:value2, ...} # diccionario

var2 = {value1, value2, ...} # set
```

Por otro lado, los *sets* de Python no soportan listas como datos, por lo que el intérprete marcará el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Una forma fácil que se me ocurre para resolver esto sería con un diccionario, el cual tendrá un key único para cada combinación referente a venta y el año (`temp_idx`) algo como:

```
r = {v1_v2:[v1, v2, v3, v4], v5_v6:[v5, v6, v7, v8], ...}
```

Si encuentra un `temp_idx`, es porque ya forma parte del diccionario, asi que solo hay que sumar los valores correspondienets a `valor[2]` y `valor[3]`. De lo contrario, entonces agregar un `temp_idx` con los 4 valores de la sublista.
[ Nota ] El último valor de `archivo.txt` dice `6,7` pero en la variable `diccionario` dice `"6","2"`. Para los resultados usé `6,2`.

```
with open("archivo.txt", "r") as f:
    data_list = f.read().strip().split("\n")

r = {}
for elem in data_list:
    venta = elem.split(',')
    temp_idx = f'{venta[0]}_{venta[1]}'
    if temp_idx in r:
        r[temp_idx][2] += int(venta[2])
        r[temp_idx][3] += int(venta[3])
    else:
        r[temp_idx] = [venta[0], venta[1], int(venta[2]), int(venta[3])]
```

Agregando un

```
print(r)
```

Se obtiene:

```
r = {venta1_2008:["venta1", "2008", 10, 5], venta4_2015:["venta4", "2015", 2, 8], ...}
```

Si solo te interesan los valores de las listas, es solo cuestión de recorrer el diccionario con un for y almacenarlos en otra lista para posterior utilización. En este caso solo se imprimirán.

```
for key, value in r.items():
    print(value)

# ["venta1", "2008", 10, 5]
# ["venta4", "2015", 2, 8]
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma muy sencilla de lograr la sumatoria de cada grupo, es mediante `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

filas = [
  ["venta1","2008","4","3"],
  ["venta4","2015","2","8"],
  ["venta1","2012","6","4"],
  ["venta3","2003","4","3"],
  ["venta2","2020","8","13"],
  ["venta1","2008","6","2"]
]

lista = sorted(filas, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))

for grupo, rows_iter in groupby(lista, lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):
  rows = list(rows_iter)
  t1 = sum(int(row[2]) for row in rows)
  t2 = sum(int(row[3]) for row in rows)
  print(grupo, t1, t2)
```

Reultado:

```
('venta1', '2008') 10 5
('venta1', '2012') 6 4
('venta2', '2020') 8 13
('venta3', '2003') 4 3
('venta4', '2015') 2 8
```

Detalle:

- Luego de leer el archivo, tienes sin duda una lista simple
- Es fundamental ordenar la misma por los dos datos clave `tipo de venta` y `año`, esto se logra configurando la clave del orden mediante una función anónima que retorne una tupla con ambos datos: `sorted(filas, key = lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))`
- Ahora simplemente resta agrupar por la misma clave: `groupby(lista, lambda x: (x[0], x[1])):`
- Lo anterior nos retorna un iterador por cada grupo y el conjunto de filas que lo componen, por lo que solo resta sumar los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes en el archivo `ventas.txt` es un archivo de valores separados por comas o un CSV. Deberia tener extensión *csv* en lugar de *txt*, pero al final también resulta ser un archivo separado por comas así tenga como extensión *txt*. Así que se le puede tratar como un archivo *csv*.

Python tiene un módulo llamado `csv`. Este permite leer un archivo de valores separados por comas, retornando los valores independientes como elementos de una lista. Para esto hay que crear un objeto `reader` que al ser iterado retornara la lista de elementos por línea de texto:

El archivo *ventas.txt*:

```
venta1,2008,4,3
venta4,2015,2,8
venta1,2012,6,4
venta3,2003,4,3
venta2,2020,8,13
venta1,2008,6,7
```

Se pondrá leer de la forma:

```
import csv

with open("ventas.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in reader:        
        print(reader)
```

Podrás ver que lo que imprime son las líneas como listas:

```
['venta1', '2008', '4', '3']
['venta4', '2015', '2', '8']
```

Así que ahora el problema esta en sumar los elementos 2 y 3 en función de la etiqueta en el elemento 0. Lo que se me ocurre es crear un diccionario del tipo:

```
{'venta1': [suma_venta_tipo_1, suma_venta_tipo_2], ...}
```

Podemos utilizar el método `setdefault(key, value)` sobre un diccionario vacío. Este método agrega un nuevo par *key:value* si es que la llave *key* no esta presente en el diccionario; de lo contrario esta instrucción no se ejecuta. Asi que llamaremos a la instrucción:

```
ventas = {}
ventas.setdefault(line[0], [0, 0])
```

Así, al leer el archivo, en la primera linea se tendrá que `line[0]` será "venta1" y como esta llave no existe se crea el registro {"venta1": [0, 0]} en el diccionario. Luego, acumulamos los valores de la lista como `int`. Todo quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
import csv

ventas = {}

with open("ventas.txt") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    
    for line in reader:
        ventas.setdefault(line[0], [0, 0])
        ventas[line[0]][0] += int(line[2])
        ventas[line[0]][1] += int(line[3])
        
print(ventas)
```

De esto resulta:

```
{'venta1': [16, 14], 'venta4': [2, 8], 'venta3': [4, 3], 'venta2': [8, 13]}
```

Si quiere extraer los datos, por ejemplo, la venta 1 de "venta1", sería:

```
ventas['venta1'][0]
```